# Shared Preferences save and retrieve data

Tags: java, android, save, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using Shared Preferences to save data from an AutoCompleteTextView.
When the user writes something in this AutoCompleteTextView, he can click a button in order to save what he just wrote (so that he doesn't have to write it every time).

Here's what my code looks like:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = null;
String nameFile = "Web service data";
String myData = "";
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
String channel = "";
String[] valuesArray = {channel};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 
    editor = pref.edit();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, valuesArray);
    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocompletion);
    autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add); 
    add.setOnClickListener(sendForm2);
    Button remove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove);
    remove.setOnClickListener(sendForm2);

    channel = pref.getString(nameFile, null);
}


OnClickListener sendForm2 = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                myData = autoComplete.getText().toString();
                editor.putString(nameFile, myData);
                editor.commit();
            break;

            case R.id.remove:
                editor.remove(nameFile);
                editor.commit();
            break;   
        }
    }   
};
```

The problem is, the Shared Preferences doesn't save any data in channel at all. Even when I close the application and restart it. 
Any clue or idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: how do you know it has not saved?

Comment: Because the input value is not in the AutoCompleteTextView after I pressed the button add and relaunched the application. I can't retrieve the value, as if the save hasn't been done.

Comment: I see you set [channel] but i don't see you doing anything with it.  not even just logging it to see if it is null

Comment: Where you read the data back from the SharedPrefernce ? Also as far as I can tell you are overwriting the latest value with the new entered one, so there won't be any list, just one value

Comment: "Channel" is stocked in the array "valuesArray" used in the AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: we don't see that happening

Comment: Alex > the line `channel = pref.getString(nameFile, null);` is where I'm supposed to read the value and store it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try would be to add a

```
Log.d("OnCreate", "channel : "+ channel);
```

in the onCreate just after

```
channel = pref.getString(nameFile, null);
```

to see if you have something inside.

If you don't, this really means that sharedpref are not saved.

In this case I would try to bring back the :

```
pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 
editor = pref.edit();
```

just before the

```
switch (v.getId()) {
```

I remember reading that sometimes depending on what you are doing with your activities, the sharedpref editor you create can be "lost" and not be related to anything later in the code.

Comment: Thanks, according to the LogCat, channel is indeed empty.

Comment: Great, Then just try my other advice and let us know !

Comment: It made the application crash, I'm gonna check and correct what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to save and retrive String prefrence.

//save the prefrence by pasing key and data

```
public static void SavePrefrence(Context ctx, String Key, String value) {
    ctx.getSharedPreferences("mypref", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit().putString(Key, value).commit();
}
```

//get the prefrence by passing your key

```
public static String getPrefrence(Context ctx, String key) {
        SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
                "mypref", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String result = pref.getString(key, null);
        return result;
    }
```